# query " COALESCE" IN SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

here is the table for PhoneGap android:

> tx.executeSql(
>                 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_prayers('id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,'prayer_id' TEXT ,'user_id'
>   INTEGER,'date' DATETIME,'status' INTEGER)",[],successCB,errorCB);

and inserting rows by the use of loop:

```
function insertInUserPrayerTable() {
                        db.transaction(function(tx)
                         {for(var i = 0;i<5;i++)
                        {checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray.push('INSERT INTO user_prayers '

                             + '(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)'
                                + ' VALUES("'
                                + checkedValueofCheckbox[i]
                                + '","'
                                + window.localStorage
                                        .getItem("userid") + '","'
                                + $('#datepicker').val() + '","'
                                + statusofNamaz[i] + '");');

                console.log("array values:"+checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray);
                        }
                         },errorCB,successCB);
            runInsertQuery();
                     }
function runInsertQuery() {
                        db
                                .transaction(
                                        function(tx) {
                                            for (var i = 0; i < checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray.length; i++) {
                                                tx
                                                        .executeSql(
                                                                checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray[i],
                                                                [],
                                                                successCBrunInsertQuery,
                                                                errorCBrunInsertQuery);
                                            }
                                        },errorCB,successCB);

                    }


$('#showbtn')
                            .off('click')
                            .on('click',
                                    function() {
                                //getRecord();
                                        db
                                                .transaction(
                                                        function(tx) {
                                                            tx.executeSql("SELECT a.date, COALESCE(a.status,'') AS 'fajr', COALESCE((SELECT b.status FROM user_prayers b WHERE b.date = a.date AND b.id != a.id LIMIT 1),'') AS 'zohar' FROM user_prayers a WHERE user_id='"+window.localStorage.getItem("userid")+"' GROUP BY a.date",[],successCBofselect,errorCBofselect);},errorCB,successCB);
```

but its not returning me status while same query is working fine in sql fiddle:

Comment: did you forget to paste the sql fiddle?

Comment: sql fiddle is not saving my fiddle thats why did not post here

Answer (score 1):

the answer is from [sqlite: is there a way to make a conditional OR / COALESCE in the SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286891/sqlite-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-conditional-or-coalesce-in-the-select-clause)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (TitleSP = '' OR TitleSP IS NULL)
            THEN COALESCE(TitleEN, '')
        WHEN (TitleEN = '' OR TitleEN IS NULL)
            THEN TitleSP
        ELSE (TitleSP || ' / ' || TitleEN)
   END AS Title,
```

...